# Parse only some of xml elements with same name

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following xml but only want to return e.g. Genre & Actors

```
<properties>
  <group>
    <name>Product properties</name>
     <property>
       <id>43560296</id>
         <name>Product Title</name>
           <value>The Ultimate Ronnie Barker Collection</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <id>43560273</id>
         <name>Genre</name>
           <value>Television</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <id>43560297</id>
         <name>Actors</name>
           <value>David Jason , Richard Beckinsale , Ronnie Barker , Fulton McKay , Nicholas Lindhurst</value>
     </property>
     <property>
      <id>43560301</id>
       <name>Publisher</name>
         <value>2 Entertain Video</value>
     </property>
  </properties>
```

Do is simply say something like:

```
  $xml->group->name->property[1]->id->name->value (for genre)

  $xml->group->name->property[2]->id->name->value (for actors)
```

Doesn't seem to work for me

Thanks for any help.

Darren

Answer (score 2):

[XPath](http://w3.org/TR/xpath/) is your friend, and is available with SimpleXML via the [`xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) method.

```
$properties = $xml->xpath('/properties/group/property[name="Genre" or name="Actors"]');
```

Also, with regards to your `$xml->group->name…` code it might be an idea to (re-)read the documentation page "[Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)".

---

**Addition**

If you want to delve into the XML to get a single matching `property` then adjust the XPath as necessary to suit.

```
$genres = $xml->xpath('/properties/group/property[name="Genre"]');
// Remember $genres is an array even if there is only one (or none) item.
echo $genres[0]->value;
```

Comment: Thank you, but in simple PHP how do i extract that into say a variable named $actors & one named $genre for each section - your help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$properties = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXMLhere);

echo $properties->group->name->property[1]->id->value;
```

and

```
echo $properties->group->name->property[2]->id->value;
```

Is correct. Give us some more code.

Edit: The XML seems broken, close `<group>` tag, and check the 'tree'. At first, `<property>` is IN `<name>`.

Comment: that is not correct since the structure goes `group->property` in the (admittedly broken) XML.